# list comprehension for opencv bgr to hex binning for colour palette. TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.uint8 object

Tags: python, opencv, hex, list-comprehension, rgb

The code below takes an opencv image, converts it to rgb, and steps through the pixels converting them to hex using a list comprehension, and counts the number of pixels there are of each colour.

How can I reduce this code using list comprehension, and solve the TypeError at the bottom ?

```
import cv2
bgr_img = cv2.imread(img_input)
rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # Hex starts with Red
```

The file is of the shape (300, 700, 3)  that is [[[ 90, 150, 140 ], [90 150 140], [90 150 140] ....

```
palette = dict()
for i in img:
    for j in i:
        colour_hex = [f"#{a:02x}{b:02x}{c:02}" for a,b,c in j]
        if colour_hex in palette:
            palette[colour_hex] +=1
        else:
            palette[colour_hex] = 1
```

So then the dictionary contains value key pairs of the hex colour and how many of each pixel in the image is that hex colour.

The error message reads

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.uint8 object

Thanks to response below, shorter code that works is like this:-

```
import cv2
bgr_img = cv2.imread(img_input)
rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # Hex starts with Red
palette = dict()
for i in img:
    for j in i:
        colour_hex = f"#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(*j)
        if colour_hex in palette:
            palette[colour_hex] +=1
        else:
            palette[colour_hex] = 1
```

can this be made any shorter ? / more Pythonic using a list comprehension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running a loop over `j` to create a list of `colour_hex` but you really just want the `colour_hex` for `j`:

Replace this:

```
colour_hex = [f"#{a:02x}{b:02x}{c:02}" for a,b,c in j]
```

With this:

```
colour_hex = "#{:02x}{:02x}{:02}".format(*j)
```

If you don't need the `bgr_img` for anything else and expect many different colours, I'd prefer this for a shorter, perhaps more Pythonic solution:

```
from cv2
from collections import defaultdict

rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(img_input), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
palette = defaultdict(int)
for i in rgb_img:
    for j in i:
        palette["#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(*j)] += 1
```

On the other hand, if you don't need the rgb_img, you can also just use the bgr_img directly, preventing the call to `cvtColor`:

```
from cv2
from collections import defaultdict

bgr_img = cv2.imread(img_input)
palette = defaultdict(int)
for i in bgr_img :
    for j in i:
        palette["#{2:02x}{1:02x}{0:02x}".format(*j)] += 1
```

Comment: This results in a Syntax Error pointing at the first bracket of

palette[f"#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(*j)] += 1

SyntaxError: f-string: empty expression not allowed